# How to get the true URL of a file on the web. (Python)

Tags: python, linux, http, unix, http-headers

I notice that sometimes audio files on the internet have a "fake" URL.

```
http://garagaeband.com/3252243
```

And this will **302** to the real URL:

```
http://garageband.com/michael_jackson4.mp3
```

My question is...when supplied with the fake URL, how can you **get the REAL URL from headers**?

Currently, this is my code for reading the headers of a file.  I don't know if this code will get me what I want to accomplish.  How do I parse out the "real" URL From the response headers?

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(head)
conn.request("HEAD",tail)
res = conn.getresponse()
```

This has a 302 redirect:
***http://www.garageband.com/mp3cat/.UZCMYiqF7Kum/01_No_pierdas_la_fuente_del_gozo.mp3***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use urllib.getUrl()

**edit:**
Sorry, I haven't done this in a while:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlopen(url).geturl()
```

For example:

```
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen("http://tinyurl.com/oex2e")
>>> f.geturl()
'http://www.amazon.com/All-Creatures-Great-Small-Collection/dp/B00006G8FI'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Mark Pilgrim advises to use [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/) in "[Dive Into Python3](http://diveintopython3.org/http-web-services.html#httplib2-redirects)" as it handles many things (including redirects) in a smarter way.

```
>>> import httplib2
>>> h = httplib2.Http()
>>> response, content = h.request("http://garagaeband.com/3252243")
>>> response["content-location"]
    "http://garageband.com/michael_jackson4.mp3"
```

Comment: While it looks like you did this interactively, you actually just wrote the expected result. Otherwise you wouldn't have "http" listed twice in your request URL and you would have seen that "garagaeband.com" (which was in the OP's description) does not actually exist and raises a "No address associated with nodename" error.

Comment: I did use an interactive session, and substituted the url with the poster's example urls :) thank you for the pointer. I am going to correct the "http://" repetition ^_^

Comment: "curl http://garagaeband.com/3252243" - "curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'garagaeband.com'" . How could the interactive session work when the domain name in your request does not exist?

Comment: As mentioned above I did use an interactive session, though with "http://deck.cc" which redirects to "http://www.deck.cc" and then substituted it with the poster's example urls because I thought it would be more illustrative.

Comment: somehow the comment system ate my "www." in the second deck.cc url =)

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the response, realize that you got a 302 (FOUND), and parse out the real URL from the response headers, then fetch the resource using the new URI.

Comment: How do I parse out the real URL form response headers?

Comment: Python's urllib and urllib2 follow the redirects for you, and keep track of the new url, as Chris Lacasse implies in his solution.

Comment: However, I can't seem to test it as I off-hand know of a server to test against and don't feel like setting one up of my own. ;)

Comment: Try a tinyurl. I believe that's a similar case

Comment: try tinyurl.com as something to test off of?

Comment: @Jeffrey Berthiaume, yes, to test the redirect

Comment: Bingo - that works. The first tinyurl I used pointed to Wikipedia, which doesn't like Python's default user agent (gave me a 403 Forbidden). Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the answer.

```
 import urllib2
    req = urllib2.Request('http://' + theurl)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    f = opener.open(req)
    print 'the real url is......' + f .url
```

Comment: There's no need for all those steps. Just do "urllib2.urlopen('http....').geturl()" as the simplest. If you want a Request object, then "urllib2.urlopen(req)" also works.